# One record spiltted into different lines in sql loader

Tags: sql, sql-loader, oracle-xe

I was trying create table in oracle express in my local database.
While importing the data, i am facing issues where some of the records appear to be in more than one line.
I used here /n to start a new line. But i feel that /n is there in between my data also that is taking one record as different records.
I used the follwoing query

```
organization external
(
type oracle_loader 
default directory ext_tab_dir
access parameters (
records delimited by '\n'
characterset 'utf8'
badfile 'SOD_RULE_SET_bad.txt' 
logfile 'SOD_RULE_SET_log.txt' 
skip 1
fields terminated by ',' Optionally Enclosed by '"'
missing field values are null 
reject rows with all null fields 
) 
location ('SOD_RULE_SET.csv')
```

Can i know how to make one records in one line, than getting it broke up.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow, but does [`continueif`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005509) do what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
organization external
(
type oracle_loader 
default directory ext_tab_dir
access parameters (
records delimited by '\r\n'
characterset 'utf8'
badfile 'SOD_RULE_SET_bad.txt' 
logfile 'SOD_RULE_SET_log.txt' 
skip 1
fields terminated by ',' Optionally Enclosed by '"'
missing field values are null 
reject rows with all null fields 
) 
location ('SOD_RULE_SET.csv')
```